# How to remove the a vector element from unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How can i remove a vector element from a unordered_map

```
std::unordered_map<std::string stdstrID, std::vector<std::string>> controlTags;
```

i will have multiple vales for a give keyname and would want to remove given value for the keyname from the vector list.

```
void Sum_TagControl::Remove_Tag(std::string stdstrControlID , std::string stdstrName) {
    
    for (auto tagData : controlTags[stdstrControlID]) {
        if (tagData == stdstrName) {
            // remove this text element from the  vector list.
        }
    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Was your intent to auto-create an empty vector in `controlTags` if one does not already exists at key `stdstrControlID` ? Because that's what this code will do. Just curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig i do create that.

Comment: if (controlTags.find(stdstrControlID) == controlTags.end()) {
  controlTags[stdstrControlID] = std::vector<Std::string>(); // Initilize the key with null vector
 }

Comment: My point was using `operator []` in the context you are will do that anyway. Anyway, back to your question. Can the vector have more than a single instance of `stdstrName`, and if so, do you want them *all* removed or just the first one? It matters. Also , if no duplicates should exist in any given vector then you may wish to consider an unordered_map of strings to unordered_set instead of vector.

Comment: the keys are `std::string`s ? `std::unordered_map<std::string stdstrID, ...` looks wrong. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Aside `stdstr` looks like some awful Hungarian notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example, it seems that you don't want to remove an element from the map, but instead you want to remove elements from a vector that happens to be within a map. That is done the same way as removing an element from any vector regardless of where it is. The typical way is remove-erase idiom.

I assume that your intention was not for `Remove_Tag` to add an empty vector in case `stdstrControlID` didn't exist in the map yet. I've fixed this in the following example:

```
auto it = controlTags.find(stdstrControlID);
if (it != controlTags.end()) {
    it->erase(std::remove(it->begin(), it->end(), stdstrName));
}
```

Note that vector erasure has linear complexity. If this is a frequently performed operation and the vector has many elements, then it would be more efficient to use an unordered (multi) set instead of a vector.